# Map cells that contain value

Tags: google-sheets

```js
=MAP(FILTER(A:A, REGEXMATCH(A:A, "Submission time:")), LAMBDA(Σ, IF(Σ = "", , IFNA(INDEX(A:A, XMATCH(Σ, A:A)-2)))))
```

The "Submission time:" rows are not unique, but the return value for each row is supposed to be unique.

```
Submission time: 2024-01-09 07:41:37
Submission time: 2024-01-09 07:41:37
Submission time: 2024-01-09 07:41:37
Submission time: 2024-01-09 07:41:37
Submission time: 2023-12-21 18:56:02
Submission time: 2023-12-21 18:56:02
Submission time: 2023-12-21 18:56:02
Submission time: 2023-12-21 18:56:02
```

How can I write it so it maps the cells that simply just contain "Submission time:"? [Here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1C1Sexm8I_YxEQGorYc-Sb6FEHT_RSn73hYPb2sfutxg/edit#gid=0&range=G2)'s an example sheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*You may try:*

```js
=let(Σ,rows(A:A),
    filter(A1:index(A:A,Σ-2),regexmatch(A3:index(A:A,Σ),"^Submission time")))
```

[image]

Comment: Sol! Thank you so much for such a quick solution - works like a charm!